# Tailwindcss @screen how to use

Tags: tailwind-css, media-queries

I would like to write these media queries in tailwind in a custom css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) or {}@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {}
```

I figured out that the correct way is to write "@screen md (or sm)" but I can't add min or max width...

Many thanks to whoever will answer me!

Answer (score 4):

`@screen` is actually quietly deprecated and thus is not documented for Tailwind v3. Instead, consider using [`screen()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#screen) like:

```css
@media screen(sm) {
  /* … */
}
```

Which would compile to:

```css
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  /* … */
}
```

If you want `max-width`, you could consider [configuring `screens`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#max-width-breakpoints):

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      foo: { 'max': '800px' },
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
  },
};
```

Then this would enable you to do:

```css
@media screen(foo) {
  /* … */
}
```

Which would compile to:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* … */
}
```

We use `theme.screens` instead of the typical `theme.extend.screens` since order can be important. Also please note that [`min-*` and `max-*`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range) variants would no longer work with this customization.

Otherwise, you could consider using `not` with `@media` which can be used to emulate `max-width` without needing to add extra `screens` configuration:

```css
@media not all and screen(sm) {
  /* … */
}
```

Which would compile to:

```css
@media not all and (min-width: 640px) {
  /* … */
}
```

Which is similar to:

```css
@media (max-width: 639px) {
  /* … */
}
```